# google-charts javascript arrayToDataTable from ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-visualization

I have this array:
["day","counts","Male","Female","AVGages"],["2012-01-20",15,10,5,25].

```
function drawChart() {
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "server.php",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
            }).responseText;

            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);
```

And a chart appears sucessfuly, with 5 columns:

["day","counts","Male","Female","AVGages"], something like this:

http://s13.postimage.org/3q2o4g2mt/chart.png

Is there a way to age dont appear as a column but still remain part of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete this column from data object before draw.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);
data.removeColumn(4);
```